# Strange BSoD with no detected causing driver

Tags: bsod

I'm getting a repeating BSoD which has no identifiable problem driver, and my diagnostic skill is mediocre. So, if anyone can help me with this, I would appreciate it.

I'm in safe mode, and it's currently not occurring.

- Win7 x64
- Alienware M14x R1
- 6GB RAM
- i7 2670QM
- Seagate Momentus 500GB SSHD (Modified from stock PC)

All stock speeds

I recently installed two drivers which were designed for my computer (prebuilt)
They were: Realtek alienware audio driver, bluetooth driver

But, as I said, there was no identified problem driver

I updated my realtek driver, and the BSoD remains.

**BSoD:**

> A problem has been detected and Windows has been shut down to prevent
>   damage to your computer.
>
> The problem seems to be caused by the following file:
>
> IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
>
> If this is the first time you've seen this stop error screen, restart
>   your computer. If this screen appears again, follow these steps:
>
> Check to make sure any new hardware or software is properly installed.
>   If this is a new installation, ask your hardware or software
>   manufacturer for any Windows updates you might need.
>
> If problems continue, disable or remove any newly installed hardware
>   or software. Disable BIOS memory options such as caching or shadowing.
>   If you need to use safe mode to remove or disable components, restart
>   your computer, press F8 to select Advanced Startup Options, and then
>   select Safe Mode.
>
> Technical Information:
>
> - STOP: 0x0000000a (0xfffffa805216d290, 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000001, 0xfffff80002ec8f23)
> - Address 0x0000000000000000 base at 0x0000000000000000 DateStamp 0x00000000

The BSoD occurs anywhere from 5-60min after startup, for no particular reason, either.

The first time it happened, I clicked an html link (or some html thing, possibly flash)
The 2nd/3rd time it happened, I was idle.

Comment: upload the .dmp files if you can't follow the steps from *user314104*

Comment: There's a few good tools for working out a BSOD - in this case I'd give [whocrashed](http://www.resplendence.com/whocrashed) a shot

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure your system is configured to create crash dumps.

Next, get and install WinDbg from the [Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279).

Open the crash dump from WinDbg as a memory dump, then do `!analyze -v` as it suggests.  It'll tell you that you need to configure symbols.

Follow the instructions in help for [configuring symbols](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503).

Do `!analyze -v` again, and this time, cross your fingers on getting the driver that violates the IRQL constraint.

Answer (score 0):

In safe mode disable your Audio hardware and Bluetooth hardware and then reset and see if the BSoD persists.  From your error codes it seems their is an IRQ hardware conflict -- one of your hardware devices are overlapping the other (or attempting to).

If the problem persists go back to Safe mode and click "Uninstall Drivers" for both devices (while still Disabled).

It's ideal we use deduction to figure this out.

Comment: Thanks guys. I figured it out from pure luck. Skype was somehow being accessed or was accessing bluetooth; I simply disabled/disallowed bluetooth's interaction with Skype, and the problem seems to be gone. But, I'll know for sure after a few days.

Comment: Never mind. It happened again. I'll try your solutions.

Comment: Ok I used whocrashed and it identified a driver from Killer Network Manager to be the problem.. I've had this issue before.. I'll update the driver and see if that works.

Comment: It worked. That was strange. I didn't do anything to Killer Net manager before this....